# Wrong output of possible values in tiles of a 4x4 grid

Tags: c

I am trying to determine all the values that could be possibly valid in each tile of a 4x4 grid.

I explain the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


main()

{
  char s[4][4]; /*digit in current tile*/
  char p[4][4][4]; /*all possible solutions for current tile*/
  int i, j, k, q;

 

  /*proper grid building*/
  printf("Enter a proper 4x4 grid with digits from 0 to 3.\nType . for empty tile.\n");
  
  for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
      scanf("%c", &s[i][j]);
      if(s[i][j] == '.' || s[i][j] >= '0' && s[i][j] <= '3')
         ;
      else{
        printf("Instructions not followed.\n");
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }

  /*prints grid*/
  for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {   
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
      printf("%c", s[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");



  /*determines all possible values on each tile*/
  for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
      if(s[i][j] == '.'){
    for(q = 0; q < 4; ++q){
      p[i][j][q] = '-';
      s[i][j] = q + '0';
      for(k = 0; k < 4; ++k){
        if(k != j && s[i][k] == s[i][j] && s[i][k] != '.' || k != i && s[k][j] == s[i][j] && s[k][j] != '.')
          p[i][j][q] = 'X';
        else if(p[i][j][q] != 'X')
          p[i][j][q] = '*';
      }
    }
  }
      else
        for(q = 0; q < 4; ++q)
          p[i][j][q] = s[i][j];
    }    
       
     
       
  printf("\n");
  for(i = 0 ; i < 4; ++i){
    printf("\ni%d \n", i);
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
      printf("j%d-- ", j);
      for(q = 0; q < 4; ++q)
        printf("q%d: %c ", q, p[i][j][q]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

After building the proper table, the program checks each tile of coordinate [i][j].

To do that, it assigns a digit [q] on a tile of coordinate [i][j].

Then, it checks if the digit clashes with the other digits on the grid. It uses the variable k to travel to other tiles of coordinates [i][k] and [j][k] and read the digit in it.

If the digit in that tile is identical to the tested digit [q] in the tile [i][j], then the value assigned to p[i][j][q] is 'X'.

If no identical digit is found in the same line or column, p[i][j][q] is '*'.

If a digit is already in the tile, all p[i][j][q] for that tile are assigned that value.

The output looks like this

```
Enter a proper 4x4 grid with digits from 0 to 3.
Type . for empty tile.

.2....1.....0...

.2..
..1.
....
0...


i0 
j0->; q0: X q1: * q2: X q3: * 
j1->; q0: 2 q1: 2 q2: 2 q3: 2 
j2->; q0: * q1: X q2: X q3: X 
j3->; q0: * q1: * q2: X q3: X 

i1 
j0->; q0: X q1: X q2: * q3: X 
j1->; q0: * q1: X q2: X q3: X 
j2->; q0: 1 q1: 1 q2: 1 q3: 1 
j3->; q0: * q1: X q2: * q3: X 

i2 
j0->; q0: X q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j1->; q0: * q1: * q2: X q3: X 
j2->; q0: * q1: X q2: * q3: X 
j3->; q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 

i3 
j0->; q0: 0 q1: 0 q2: 0 q3: 0 
j1->; q0: X q1: * q2: X q3: X 
j2->; q0: X q1: X q2: * q3: X 
j3->; q0: X q1: * q2: * q3: X
```

Each paragraph is an [i] coordinate, each line is a [j] coordinate. Thus each line corresponds to a tile. In this tile we check all values from 0 to 3 and determine if this digit would fit in the tile.

For example, the tile [0][1] contains a 2. So the tile next to it, [0][2], cannot contain a 2 so p[0][2][2] is assigned an X.

Now the problem is that the last column of the output, so the p[i][j][3], is wrong. It seems to see ghost 3s. Here is the output of an empty table.

```
....
....
....
....


i0 
j0-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: * 
j1-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j2-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j3-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 

i1 
j0-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j1-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j2-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j3-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 

i2 
j0-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j1-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j2-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j3-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 

i3 
j0-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j1-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j2-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X 
j3-- q0: * q1: * q2: * q3: X
```

As you can see all the p[i][j][3] are assigned an X, except for the first tile.

I'm puzzled.

Can you please explain what causes this behaviour?

Comment: This question is a lot to wade through. What does "valid" mean in this context? Is it possible to simplify what you are asking to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You are right in that I didn't define what valid means.
Valid here means that no other tile in the same line or column contains the same digit.

As for simplifying, I tried to explain the best I could what each variable does and what was the goal of the code. All the blocks in the code I've given are necessary to produce the output I've shown. There is one example of a normal use of the program, and one obvious example that shows it doesn't work properly. I don't know what to remove honestly.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &s[i][j]);` --> `scanf(" %c", &s[i][j]);`.   Add space.